# Running SoundPool on Background with AsyncTask

Tags: android, background, android-asynctask

I am trying to play 5 SoundPool one after the other on Background using AsyncTask for it. But I wanna click an ImageView while sounds are running. The problem begins when SoundPool uses getBaseContext() that blocks my ImageView while doInBackground is running.
Does anyone know whats happening?
Thxs a lot!
Here is my code:

```
    public class SensoriomotoraActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean playing = false ;
    private ImageView image ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sensoriomotora);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_sensoriomotora_pandereta);

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
           if (playing){
            Log.v("onClick","clicked while playing");   
           }
           else {
            Log.v("onClick","clicked while !playing");  
           }
         }
        });


        new Thread (
                new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        // Waiting 2.5 secs before playing the beeps
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    new PlaySoundBackground().execute();
                                }
                         });
                    }
                }
          ).start(); 
   }


    private class PlaySoundBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           playing = true ;
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

           SoundPool sound;

           sound = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
           sound.load(getBaseContext(), R.raw.beep, 1);
           sound.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {

              @Override
              public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                for (int i=0 ; i<5; i++){
                    soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000); // Waits 2 secs before next beep
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
              }
           });
           return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           playing = false ;
      }       
  }
}
```

Comment: Question could stand to be clearer, particularly: "SoundPool uses getBaseContext() that blocks my ImageView while doInBackground is running" ... what do you mean specifically by "blocks my ImageView"?

You may want to call SoundPool.load() ahead of time (before you need to play the sound). If you are loading compressed audio (like OGG, MP3), then the call to load() will convert it into raw 16-bit audio, and this consumes resources. It might potentially "block" your UI (make it unresponsive, sluggish)

Comment: getBaseContext is not a blocking call.  In fact, it just returns a member variable.  If you are suggesting that something is blocking, you might want to performing timing around the things you think are slow and report those here.  What is exactly is the slow thing here?

Comment: I just realized this is a super old issue, lol, sorry for the spam.